# Locating and reading a file stored locally

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a metro app and I have added an existing file into a folder inside solution explorer. I have read the resources docs on msdn but can't get it figured out.

[image]

My sound file is located in `Assets\SFX\Standard.wav`, so how would I locate and play this file using `MediaElement` in my app from codebehind?

Comment: \Assets\SFX\Standard.wav, a "\" at the start defines root of the project

Comment: So whatever code I am using to find/load/play the file, I just need to pass: `"\Assets\SFX\Standard.wav"` as the path to this file?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you would want to use `MediaElement`, perhaps you could try `SoundPlayer`?

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();

player.SoundLocation = "\Assets\SFX\Standard.wav";
player.Play();
```

Edit with MediaElement:

```
<MediaElement Name="TehSoundz" IsLooping="False" AutoPlay="False" Height="0" Width="0" Source="\Assets\SFX\Standard.wav" />
```

Codebehind:

```
TehSoundz.Play();
TehSoundz.Stop();
```

Comment: SoundPlayer is not available in Windows Store RT (Metro) apps, unfortunately.

Comment: Things aren't that simple anymore :( And there's no good reason why they shouldn't be.

Comment: @jAsOn OK, I will look for another solution.